# Change content but same page in address bar with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want when someone type site.com/page.php to redirect and show content from site.com/page1.php but in address bar to stay and show site.com/page.php.

How can I do this? 
I use this now

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/stranica\.php$ /page.php
```

but this change also the page in address bar.

Is it possible with .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^stranica\.php$ /page.php [L]
```

You need the LAST flag and without redirect portion to do an internal redirect.